# django NOT NULL constraint failed error

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I am having an error in the form django.db.utils.IntegrityError: NOT NULL constraint failed:

in my app I ask the user to create a new project and then is ask via a form to add team member name mail.if the mail already exist in the database the user is invited to by mail to login to the app if the mail is not in the database the user is asked by mail to sign in. Then the invited member is added to the team.

I am getting that error when trying to assign an existing user in the data base

here is my code :

```
def TeamRegister2(request):
    #import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
    InviteFormSet = formset_factory(InviteForm2)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        formset = InviteFormSet(request.POST)

        if(formset.is_valid()):
            for i in formset:
                mail = i.cleaned_data['Email']
                if MyUser.objects.filter(email = mail).exists():
                    user = MyUser(email = mail)
                    u1 = user.id # get user ID
                    a1 = MyUser.objects.get(email = request.user.email) #get user email
                    a2 = Project.objects.filter(project_hr_admin = a1)  #get all project created by the user
                    a3 = a2.latest('id') # extract the last project
                    a4 = a3.team_id # extract the team linked to the project
                    a4.members.add(u1) # add the member to the team

                    invited_user = MyUser.objects.get(email = mail)
                    current_site = get_current_site(request)
                    message = render_to_string('acc_join_email.html', {
                        'user': invited_user.first_name,
                        'domain':current_site.domain,
                        })
                    mail_subject = 'You have been invited to SoftScores.com please LogIn to get access to the app'
                    to_email = mail
                    email = EmailMessage(mail_subject, message, to=[to_email])
                    email.send()
                else:
                    user = MyUser(email = mail)
                    password = MyUser.objects.make_random_password()
                    user.set_password(password)
                    user.is_active = False
                    user.is_employee = True
                    user.save()
                    u1 = user.id #get user id
                    a1 = MyUser.objects.get(email = request.user.email) #get user email
                    a2 = Project.objects.filter(project_hr_admin = a1)  #get all project created by the user
                    a3 = a2.latest('id') # extract the last project
                    a4 = a3.team_id # extract the team linked to the project
                    a4.members.add(u1) # add the member to the team

                    current_site = get_current_site(request)
                    message = render_to_string('acc_active_email.html', {
                    'user':user,
                    'domain':current_site.domain,
                    'uid': urlsafe_base64_encode(force_bytes(user.pk)),
                    'token': account_activation_token.make_token(user),
                    })
                    mail_subject = 'You have been invited to SoftScores.com please sign in to get access to the app'
                    to_email = user.email
                    email = EmailMessage(mail_subject, message, to=[to_email])
                    email.send()
            messages.success(request, 'testouille la fripouille')
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('website:ProjectDetails', kwargs={'pk':a3.id}))
        else:
            print("The entered form is not valid")

    else:
        formset = InviteFormSet()
    return render(request,'team_register.html', {'formset':formset})
```

MyUser Model:

```
class MyUser(AbstractBaseUser):
    email = models.EmailField(
        verbose_name='email address',
        max_length=255,
        unique=True,
    )
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=150, blank=True, null=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=150, blank=True, null=True)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_hr = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_candidate = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_employee = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    company = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
```

Team model:

```
class Team(models.Model):
    team_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, default = '')
    team_hr_admin = models.ForeignKey(MyUser, blank=True, null=True)
    members = models.ManyToManyField(MyUser, related_name="members")

def __str__(self):
    return self.team_name
```

Project models:

```
class Project(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    team_id = models.ForeignKey(Team, blank=True, null=True)
    project_hr_admin = models.ForeignKey('registration.MyUser', blank=True, null=True)
    candidat_answers = models.ManyToManyField('survey.response')
```

any idea how to fix that error and add the user to the team ? 
thx you ;)

traceback:

```
File "/Users/raphaelbendenoun/anaconda/envs/myDjangoEnv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py" in execute
  65.                 return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)

File "/Users/raphaelbendenoun/anaconda/envs/myDjangoEnv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py" in execute
  328.         return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)

The above exception (NOT NULL constraint failed: website_team_members.myuser_id) was the direct cause of the following exception:

File "/Users/raphaelbendenoun/anaconda/envs/myDjangoEnv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py" in inner
  41.             response = get_response(request)

File "/Users/raphaelbendenoun/anaconda/envs/myDjangoEnv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  187.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "/Users/raphaelbendenoun/anaconda/envs/myDjangoEnv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  185.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "/Users/raphaelbendenoun/Documents/Django Projects/Authentication_project/registration/views.py" in TeamRegister2
  85.                     a4.members.add(u1) # add the member to the team

File "/Users/raphaelbendenoun/anaconda/envs/myDjangoEnv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related_descriptors.py" in add
  934.                 self._add_items(self.source_field_name, self.target_field_name, *objs)

File "/Users/raphaelbendenoun/anaconda/envs/myDjangoEnv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related_descriptors.py" in _add_items
  1103.                         for obj_id in new_ids

File "/Users/raphaelbendenoun/anaconda/envs/myDjangoEnv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in bulk_create
  443.                 ids = self._batched_insert(objs_without_pk, fields, batch_size)

File "/Users/raphaelbendenoun/anaconda/envs/myDjangoEnv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in _batched_insert
  1099.                 self._insert(item, fields=fields, using=self.db)

File "/Users/raphaelbendenoun/anaconda/envs/myDjangoEnv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in _insert
  1076.         return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(return_id)

File "/Users/raphaelbendenoun/anaconda/envs/myDjangoEnv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py" in execute_sql
  1107.                 cursor.execute(sql, params)

File "/Users/raphaelbendenoun/anaconda/envs/myDjangoEnv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py" in execute
  80.             return super(CursorDebugWrapper, self).execute(sql, params)

File "/Users/raphaelbendenoun/anaconda/envs/myDjangoEnv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py" in execute
  65.                 return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)

File "/Users/raphaelbendenoun/anaconda/envs/myDjangoEnv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/utils.py" in __exit__
  94.                 six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)

File "/Users/raphaelbendenoun/anaconda/envs/myDjangoEnv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/six.py" in reraise
  685.             raise value.with_traceback(tb)

File "/Users/raphaelbendenoun/anaconda/envs/myDjangoEnv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py" in execute
  65.                 return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)

File "/Users/raphaelbendenoun/anaconda/envs/myDjangoEnv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py" in execute
  328.         return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)

Exception Type: IntegrityError at /registration/auth_team_register3/
Exception Value: NOT NULL constraint failed: website_team_members.myuser_id
```

Comment: Please show your TeamMembers table

Comment: updated .... ;)

Comment: Please copy error traceback as well.

Comment: done ..........

Comment: Have you tried making migrations and migrating the database?

Comment: Yes even if I did not modified my models I did it in a case but it is not helping .. using import pdb; pdb.set_trace() the error happen when I add the user to the team  a4.members.add(u1). Do you think it is because my model is not set to give a user to be part of multiple teams ?

Comment: @Sanndeep Balagopal  I modified to a4.members.add(user) and get ValueError: Cannot add "<MyUser: jason@gmail.com>": instance is on database "default", value is on database "None"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to add an unsaved `MyUser` instance to the manytomany field. You have to get the object instead of creating a new object.

```
user = MyUser.objects.get(email=mail)
a4.members.add(user)
```

Comment: I get UnboundLocalError: local variable 'email' referenced before assignment